# java list of objects that all implement an interface

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have a class that implements an interface:

```
public class A implements IB
```

and I have a `List<A>` that I would like to reference to: `List<? implements IB> list`.
So that I can code: `for (IB item : list)` etc.

Can it be done somehow in Java? There is no `<? implements ...>` possibility.
What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean IA? when you say IB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant that class A implements IA, rather than IB, then your code should be just fine saying

```
for (A item : list) {
    // handle item as if it is an IA
}
```

since all As are, by definition IAs.

Meanwhile, there is no wildcard for `<? implements C>`.  There is `<? extends C>`, and `C` can be an interface or a class; however, this isn't necessary for what you seem to be trying to do.

If you want expressly to say `for (IA item : list)` because you're not guaranteeing that items in that list are `A`s, but are guaranteeing that they are `IA`s, then I think you have a slight problem (I can't tell for sure, since you didn't say where this list processing code is located).  A `List<A>` is *not* a `List<IA>` by definition; if you're building a `List<A>` and then passing it to a method that expects a `List<IA>`, you'll get a compile time error.  You can, however, create a `List<IA>` and fill it with `A`s.  The reason for this is explained in Java's tutorial on generics.

Comment: What was I thinking? It works perfectly well because in <? extends C> C can also be an interface. I thought 'extends' <=> inheritance.

Comment: > The reason for this is explained in Java's tutorial on generics.

Here's the link to the relevant section: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Answer (score 22):

Use `extends`:

```
public void someMethod(List<? extends IB> list) {
  for (IB e : list) {
    // Perform some processing on each element.
  }
}

public void anotherMethod() {
  List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
  someMethod(list);
}
```

More information can be found at [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) which has a [comprehensive lesson on Generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

In particular, the [section on wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) explains how to use the `?` with `super` and `extends` to specify a parameter to be one that is a superclass or subclass of a given class.

Comment: I recommend also the session from Joshua Bloch from JavaOne this year for more info.  Really cleared it up for me: http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/sessions/2009/pdf/TS-5217.pdf

Comment: this is an excellent solution thanks coolbird

Comment: @amischiefr - do you have a link to Joshua Bloch's talk?

Answer (score 8):

What about:

```
List<? extends IA> list;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `extends`:

```
List<? extends IA> list
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could declare it a `List<IA>`.

To build upon this further, List can store any objects that implement IA in it.  The catch is that, when retrieving them back out, you don't know the original class without doing a `.getClass()` on it.

Example:

```
List<IA> list = new ArrayList<IA>();
// code to populate list here
for (IA item : list) {
    item.iaMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that don't need to use `List<? extends IB> list`

```java
public class A implements IB{

}

List<A> listOfConcreteClassA = new ArrayList<A>();

// convert to interface
List<IB> listOfInterfaceB = new ArrayList<IB>(listOfConcreteClassA)
```